# ReactCSSTransitionGroup leave no Effect

Tags: javascript, reactjs, css-transitions, reactcsstransitiongroup

I'm trying to animate an array of items from my state with *ReactCSSTransitionGroup*. The `appear` and `enter` classes work fine, but the `leave` class won't trigger. I'm removing the Items in my reducer with

```
state.deleteIn(['globalArray','array'])
```

and fill it with

```
state.setIn(['globalArray', 'array'], action.newItems)
```

Render function:

```
 return (
<ReactCSSTransitionGroup transitionAppearTimeout={2000} transitionEnterTimeout={10000}
                         transitionLeaveTimeout={10000} transitionName={animation} transitionAppear={true}>
  <Paper zDepth={2}>

      <ReactImageFallback
        src={ item.imagesrc }
        fallbackImage={ item.imagesrc }
      />
  </Paper>
</ReactCSSTransitionGroup>)
```

Css (just for testing):

```
.enter {
}

.enter.enterActive {
}

.leave {
    transform: translate(+100%,+50%) ;
}

.leave.leaveActive {
    transition-timing-function: ease-in;
}

.appear {
    opacity: 0;
    transform: translate(-100%,-50%) ;
}

.appear.appearActive {
    transition-duration: 5s ;
    transition-timing-function: ease-out;
}
```

I'm also using cssNext.
Is there a workaround to get the leave class triggered on delete?

Comment: ReactCSSTransitionGroup has nothing to do with Immutable or Redux. It should work seamlessly. Can you post your rendering code ?

Comment: What css are you using?

Comment: Okay, but how can you trigger this leave effect if the whole component is based on the state? I don't get why the appear class is added and the leave  class not.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You update your state but you don't use it to render your elements (or at least not from the code you shared).

If you want your `Paper` to be animated on enter or leave based on your component's state. For instance :

```
render() {
    let items = this.state.items.map(item => (
        <Paper zDepth={2} key={/* unique key or index here */}>
            <ReactImageFallback
                src={ item.imagesrc }
                fallbackImage={ item.imagesrc }
            />
        </Paper>
    ));
    return (
        <ReactCSSTransitionGroup /*transitionE... props here */>
            {items}
        </ReactCSSTransitionGroup>
    );
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I was experiencing the same thing and tracked the issue down to the fact that I was removing the `ReactCSSTransitionGroup` component from the page when I should have just been removing the desired element within it, ie

This (works):

```
render() {
  return (
    <div>
      <ReactCSSTransitionGroup /*...props...*/>
        {display && <ItemToRemoveFromPage />}
      </ReactCSSTransitionGroup>
    </div>
  );
}
```

Instead of this (does not work):

```
render() {
  return (
    <div>
      {display && (
        <ReactCSSTransitionGroup /*...props...*/>
          <ItemToRemoveFromPage />
        </ReactCSSTransitionGroup>
      )}
    </div>
  );
}
```